# Como le doy estilos CSS a un icono agregado como clase de icomoon.io

Tags: css

Ya estoy por terminar mi 12 página web y quiero saber cómo modificar los iconos que se agregan como clase, de esos que se descargan de icomoon.io. El código de los iconos viene así:

```
.icon-add-to-list:before { content: "\e900"; }
```

Y están en una carpeta llamada "fonts", la cual llamo utilizando un link con su nombre. Lo agregue en un `div` y a ese `div` le puse la clase con el nombre "icon-add-to-list:before" y de esta manera aparece el icono.

Pero me dejo en duda que le di estilos de posición y sí los respeto todos márgenes etc, pero no me dejo darle efecto `hover` para cambiarle de tamaño, color, etc

¿Cómo puedo lograr eso?

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta un poco de información: ¿qué estilos tienen ahora? ¿Cómo quieres cambiar los estilos? ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo del código?

Comment: Hola buenos dias , muchas gracias por tu ayuda , si esque me descarge unos iconos de icomoon.io y vienen asi :`.icon-add-to-list:before {
    content: "\e900";`
}

Comment: Bienen en una carpeta llamada fonts , la cual llamo utilizando un link con su nombre y por ejemplo , lo agregue en un div y a ese div le puse la clase con el nombre  **(icon-add-to-list:before)**  y de esta manera aparece el icono , pero me dejo en duda que le di estilos de posicion y si los respeto todos margenes etc , pero no me dejo darle efecto hover , para cambiarle de tamaño , color etc

Comment: Una disculpa , creo que use mal el formato de escritura , solo queria resaltar una pequeña parte

Comment: He cambiado la pregunta un poco con los datos que pusiste en los comentarios. Por favor, revísalo para ver que es correcto y lo que quieres.

Comment: Debería permitirlo, normalmente lo que contiene la propiedad `content` no es más que "texto", por consiguiente es como si le dieras estilo a un texto. Verifica que no están siendo sobreescritos por otros estilos.

Comment: Si , gracias alvaro guardare un screen de el formato , ya que me e equivocado al usarlo .

Comment: Shaz , exactamente verificare eso porque no me ha permitido modificarle los estilos de esa manera.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias , Alvaro y Shaz , an resuelto mi duda y problema , les dare la mejor puntuacion XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los iconos de icomoon se añaden a través de una fuente vectorial en el `content` de `:before`. Si quieres añadirles estilos específicos para el `hover` debes especificarlos con `:hover:before`. Por ejemplo:

```
.icon-add-to-list:hover:before { content: "\e900"; color:blue; }
```

Aquí dejo una demo en la que el icono (puede que se vea sólo un cuadrado porque no esté disponible ese carácter en la fuente utilizada) se verá rojo en estado normal y azul cuando se pasa el ratón por encima:

```css
.icon-add-to-list::before { content: "\e900"; color:red } 

.icon-add-to-list:hover::before { content: "\e900"; color:blue }
```

```html
<div class="icon-add-to-list"></div>
```

Comment: Un microcomentario: la sintaxis en CSS3 es `::before`, mientras la que tienes es de CSS2.

Comment: @Shaz Tienes toda la razón. Lo he editado para ponerlo de esa manera